# mern stack: html is loading but react is not compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Ok I'm not getting an error message here or anything but I'm trying to start a react app with node and only the Html is being sent. Am I missing something here?

I've tried the

```
    <script type="text/babel" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

solution but it's refusing to execute the index.js still.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="public/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="public/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Parker Call</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/babel" src="../src/index.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const validator = require("express-validator");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    const session = require("cookie-session");
    const expressSession = require("express-session");
    const path = require("path");

    const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

    let app = express()
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .set('view engine','ejs')
    .use(express.static("views"))
    .use(cookieParser())
    // .use(expressSession({
    //     secret : 'soooosecret',
    //     resave : true,
    //     saveUninitialized : false
    // }))
    .use(session({keys: ['secretkey1', 'secretkey2', '...']}))

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'react-bootstrap-test', 'views')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'public', 'index.html'))
      });


     app.listen(port);
     console.log('Server running at 80');
```

index.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';


    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It should be giving me a react app but it's just a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.js file, which you're importing via the script tag

```
<script type="text/babel" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

contains JSX rather than Javascript.

This is something that browsers don't understand, so it needs to be transpiled into Javascript.

Depending on your setup, you may have a build command that will take the JSX, bundle in the React libraries and give you a file that will happily work in your page.

If producing a build is not something that's available to you, the quickest way to get up and running is to include the React and React DOM libraries from a CDN (see [this page for more details](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html)) as well as Babel, which will handle the transpiling from JSX to JavaScript.

Using the example you provided, if I add the following three script imports to your index.html, then I can see the correct output.

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
```

Be aware, that if you're doing this approach and using any other third party libraries (such as moment.js) then you'll need to include these too in your index.html.

Comment: Ok I had no idea about the build command. Thanks a million dude that problem held this project back for days.